# how to fix 'jspm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: jspm

I install jspm in https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/wiki/Getting-Started.
npm install jspm -g.
It run.
and I call it: jspm install, it not run,cmd notice "'jspm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
help me, please!

Comment: jspm isn't in your PATH. You must to add its path to your PATH .

Comment: sometimes restarting a console/shell can fix those issues as it will reload environment variables (that is if it is in your path)

Answer (score 4):

Adding  %appdata%\npm in environment variables under PATH worked for me.

Comment: Me too, found tip from https://alanfeekery.com/2015/09/30/jspm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-or-command-not-found/

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and what I have tried and worked for me was to start **cmd.exe as an administrator.**

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\dev\GitHub\JspmTest

C:\dev\GitHub\JspmTest>jspm -v
0.15.7
Running against local jspm install.

C:\dev\GitHub\JspmTest>

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a PATH entry to my windows user env vars, *not* system. 
System was not expanding %APPDATA% because APPDATA was set in user env vars.

Then add %appdata%\npm to PATH in user env vars

JSPM was then accessible anywhere from command.

The entry in user PATH is appended at the end of system PATH, you don't lose your system PATH.