# jspm init command does not work, I really stuck. any help will be appreciated

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, jspm

**Hello all**,
 I have install jspm globlly and locally at my-project directory, but when I type jspm init to the console it returns that 'jspm' is not recognized as a command. 
I have stuck on for more than one day, how can I solve this, thank you

N.B. I have researched for it immensely but i can't solve it

Comment: This question isn't related to Angular, so I have removed the tag. Other than that, welcome to SOF, please read [ask] before submitting a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pick the correct answer after great efforts it's present here [how to fix 'jspm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355807/how-to-fix-jspm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable) but it's not an obvious answer, so let solve the problem step by step:

1. first go to system properties with win+R and type sysdm.cpl
2. go to advance tab then to enviroment variables tab at bottom right,
   then in the user variable pane under path variable click edit then
   click new then add this :**`%appdata%\npm`** then it will run god willing.